# My code compiles with errors but executes fine at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, compiler-errors, runtime

I have a class named X which implements Connection interface from java.sql package.We are using java 1.6 and everything is working fine.Oracle has introduced some 4 new methods in Connection interface in java 1.7.When I build my code with JRE set as 1.7(in Build path of Eclipse) the code does not  compile and has following error

The type BrmPcmConnection must implement the inherited abstract method Connection.abort(Executor)

I understand Connection.abort is the new method introduced in Java 7 and i need to implement it.I have the same code which was compiled using 1.6 and it runs fine on 1.7 JRE!

Please help me understand,why the code compiles with error but at runtime there are no exceptions.Is it due to that during runtime no one is invoking the new methods?

Comment: Or perhaps you are running an old version. Clean your project files and recompile.

Comment: Maybe you could show us the code that causes that error? Show us the abstract base class and the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile an application you have to implement all the abstract method of super classes.  However, say you have a program which has been compiled, and you change a super class or interface by adding a method what happens?

The JVM will try to run the program and this is all fine provided you don't actually call that method.  If you call the method, which would be hard to do if you compiled in a version which didn't have it, you will get a runtime Error.

But don't call a method you don't have and it all works.

If you don't have an implementation for these methods I suggest adding

```
// @Override 
public void setSchema(String pSchema) throws SQLException { 
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

You could also `throw new SQLException("Not implemented")` in this case.

Note: I have commented out `@Override` so it still compiles in older version.

Comment: This is interesting behaviour that I've never thought of but it makes complete sense. I guess this means that you can _technically_ update published interfaces without breaking implementations for its users. Although if the user needs to re-compile then they'll be in trouble. Good answer and thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson In Java 8 you can add methods with `default` implementations which creates less issues.

Comment: Thanks.My class is a pure class and not abstract.So to get rid of these compile errors can I just add a default implementation of the new methods in  the interface.I am saying if setSchema is the new method oracle has added.Can i just ad

Comment: @Override
    public void setSchema(String pSchema) throws SQLException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
    }
Basically it does nothing.Its there to comply with interface.I hope it does not break the code with any other side effects.

Comment: @AshishThakur I have added an example. Unless you know the method can be ignored, I would throw an exception.

Comment: I understood now.Thanks @Peter Lawrey

Comment: please note that Eclipse does compile code with errors, that is, it creates valid `.class` files. The compiled code can be executed but it will throw an Error (`java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`) if the impacted code is executed. Code not *related* to the error will be executed normally.