# java se 8 rules for implementing abstract methods from extended interfaces

Tags: java, interface, abstract, extends

why does this code compile printing "Class 2" (java se8; eclipse) even if abstract method is NOT implemented in first concrete class?

IDE gives me the hint: The type Class1 must implement the inherited abstract method
Interface1.method1()

```
package uebungen.u025;



interface Interface1 {
        public void method1();
    }

    interface Interface2 extends Interface1 {// line n1
        public void method2();
    }

    class Class1 implements Interface2 {// line n2
        @Override
        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("Class 1");
        }
    }

        class Class2 extends Class1 {// line n3
            @Override
            public void method2() {
                System.out.println("Class 2");
            }

        }

        public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                Class1 x = new Class2();
                x.method2();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the IDE hint is correct. `Book` is also a `Downloadable`, so it must implement the `download` method.

Comment: Did you mean the `Book` class to be abstract? If it was abstract, it would pass compilation, and `EBook` wouldn't. Since it's not abstract, `Book` doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: By the way, the compiler simply couldn't compile `EBook` because `Book` is not available, so it didn't even try, that's why you don't see an error for `EBook` as well.

Comment: for me it does not **successfully** compile - I get the mentioned **error**  - see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwmYU.png) Eclipse 2023-12 || Yes, it does give the *hint*, but it is marked as an error - if you try to execute it, Eclipse will show "Errors in Workspace | Errors exist in required project(s) ..."  -- you are probably confused since Eclipse has the *functionality* to still compile the code, but it will throw an Exception (`java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`) if you try to run the code part that is impacted by the error (`book1.download()` in this example)

Comment: Federico is right, error source is simply the fact that Book doesn't implement download method, so you have 2 way: make Book abstract if you want use it just like a "template" or implement `download` method. Tbh, in a real world scenario the structure seems not correct ... not all books are downloadable, so for a better representation, just EBook should implements Downloadable

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi I do not think that the question is about what the error source is. The question is "*why does this code compile*", that is, Eclipse will compile and execute the posted code, printing `read e-book` and terminating without runtime errors

Comment: I wonder why this question is marked to be closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"!  I can very well reproduce it - at least using Eclipse (as being asked for) !  @LaVeron: maybe the question should be better explained, including that the code can be executed without runtime errors and giving the expected output...

Comment: maybe [My code compiles with errors but executes fine at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39347943/85421)

Comment: thank you for your answers <3 . but I dont know if it was allowed to share this code on the internet, so I will delete it and change the code -.-